# How can I make an HTML clickable button with its value autofilled from an SQL search result?

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a button in which it grabs the value from the SQL 2008 server and then becomes the POST data.  Here's what I've been trying:

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/php_orderview.php">

<input type="text" name="order_ID">

<?php echo $row['order_ID']?>

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="View">
</form>
```

This just comes up with an empty box.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
<input type="text" name="order_ID" value="<?php echo $row['order_ID']?>">
```

basic html form, value attribute is the text in the box

Comment: Do not forget to pass data from db through `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: as its order_ID i assume itsjust an int

Comment: I can guarantee that next one is going to be `username` or `order_description` ;)

Comment: I'll make more points when he comes back and asks a new question :-)

Comment: Oh yeah.  That's what happens when I switch to html after a long day.  Thanks for the solution.  The other problem I had was that I needed to make another <td> for the submit button.  Don't worry, I'll have some more easy questions later in the day I'm sure.